# Weird Connection exception with retrofit and OkHttp

Tags: android, retrofit, okhttp

Our server went down, but before I noticed it was down I got the following exceptions repeatedly every time I made a network call:

```
D/Retrofit: ---- ERROR https://RETRACTED/
D/Retrofit: java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to localhost/127.0.0.1 (port 443) after 30000ms: isConnected failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)
```

Though a connection exception is expected, the log should be pointing to the hostname of the request, not to localhost.

Additional notes: The internet was working both on browsers and other apps, this happened in a real device - HTC One.

Comment: Can you reproduce this? My guess is that localhost is being used as an HTTP proxy as a fallback somewhere. You should print the Route and maybe also the ProxySelector to see if that's the case.

Comment: @JesseWilson After a while it went back to the actual hostname, and I could not reproduce it ever since.